# Как правильно организовать обработку данных в экшене контроллера?

Tags: php, laravel, проектирование

Задался вопросом простых и гибких экшинов в контроллерах. Собственно используя свой подход к проектированию столкнулся с проблемами, для решения которых хочу воспользоваться вашими советами. 
*Примеры на laravel5*

**Контроллер:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\TestRequest;
use App\Services\TestService;
use Exception;
use Session;
use DB;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    protected $testService;


    public function __construct(TestService $testService)
    {
        $this->testService = $testService;
    }


    public function index(TestRequest $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {

            $result = $this->testService->process($request->all());

            if ($result) {
                DB::commit();

                // Данные сохранены успешно

            } else {
                DB::rollBack();

                // Ошибка сохранения данных

            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            // Ошибка обработки данных
        }

        //return redirect || view;
    }

}
```

**Сервис**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use ErrorException;

class TestService
{
    public function process(array $data)
    {
        // Логика и аналитика для получания переменной $var
        $var = 7;

        if ($var > $data['count']) {
            throw new ErrorException('Возникла критическая ошибка, ...');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Реквест**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use HttpResponseException;
use Validator;
use Response;

class TestRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $this->sanitize();

        return [
            // rules
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function sanitize()
    {
        $input = $this->all();
        $input['var1'] = filter_var(isset($input['var1']) ? $input['var1'] : null, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $input['var2'] = filter_var(isset($input['var2']) ? $input['var2'] : null, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $input['var3'] = filter_var(isset($input['var3']) ? $input['var3'] : null, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $this->replace($input);
    }

}
```

**Возник вопрос/проблема с валидацией данных**

По хорошему валидацию должен делать реквест, однако довольно часто происходят ситуации, в которых  мне нужно проверить есть ли запись в таблице и сразу с ней работать. Тоесть выходит 2 запроса, 1 - через валидаторы фреймворка, а 2 - когда в контроллере или сервисе достаем эту-же запись для дальнейшей работы.

В добавок к этому иногда логика может быть достаточно замысловатой, поэтому чтобы получить некие данные для валидации, нужно проделать ряд логических действий. Мне не очень нравится идея выносить куски логики в реквест (даже если протягивать сервисы в реквест), чтобы сделать валидацию, а потом почти тоже самое, чтобы в сервисе продолжить работать с этим делом.

Соответственно получается неудобная ситуация, когда часть валидации нужно разместить в реквесте, а часть в сервисе. Еще остается проблема рендеринга ошибок, когда у нас получается два типа валидации, реквест и валидация по средствам эксепшинов из сервисов.

Подскажите пожалуйста (желательно на примерах псевдокода), как это красиво оформить ?
Буду очень признателен за развернуты ответы по этому вопросу.

Answer (score -1):

> логика может быть достаточно замысловатой, поэтому чтобы получить некие данные для валидации, нужно проделать ряд логических действий. Мне не очень нравится идея выносить куски логики в реквест (даже если протягивать сервисы в реквест), чтобы сделать валидацию, а потом почти тоже самое, чтобы в сервисе продолжить работать с этим делом.

Попробуйте вынести конкретную логику в метод модели, и использовать его в реквесте и в далее где необходимо.

> То есть выходит 2 запроса, 1 - через валидаторы фреймворка, а 2 - когда в контроллере или сервисе достаем эту-же запись для дальнейшей работы.

Тут можно при запросе например в валидации добавлять кеширование ~ на 1 минуту, чтобы не выполнялся такой же запрос, а также используйте связи между моделями, они кешируются, если запрашивать как коллекцию(без скобок) `$model->relation->..`.